# How to make input write to file? - Batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I was making a small game where you make a car and name it.

After you made the car, this would be the screen:

```
:HatchC3_1  
set /a money=%money% - 2000  
cls  
echo   You put a V4 1.2L engine in your car.  
echo.  
echo   Now, the car is complete.   
echo   All that is left is to name it.  

set /p carname=Enter:  
//(Here is where the name would be written to a file)   
goto carsale
```

and then it'd get written to a text file, but I don't know how to do that.
(Sorry if really bad question, if I didn't explain enough, write it in the comments)

EDIT: Is there a way to make the variable not overwrite each time a car is made and saved?

Comment: `set %money% - 2000`? I hope, this is a bunch of typos only. If you want to set the variable `%money%` to `2000`, syntax is: `set money=2000` (and please don't put spaces before or after the `=`)

Comment: @Stephan it was a typo, I forgot that it had to be set /a money=%money% - 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo %carname% > mycar.txt
```

Should do what you want.

If you want to append cars then you could use the `>>` redirection operator.

```
echo %carname% >> mycar.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set carname=
```

May do what you want, it clears the variable after write to file. The Subroutine would be:

```
@echo off
:Carsale
cls
echo The car is %carname%
pause
set carname=
goto HatchC3_1
```